# Azure automation: can I use runbook for compute-intensive tasks

Tags: azure, azure-automation

I try to compare several similar (from some point of view) tools:

- [Automation runbooks](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/automation-create-runbook-from-samples/)

  > Microsoft Azure Automation provides a way for users to automate the
  >   manual, long-running, error-prone, and frequently repeated tasks that
  >   are commonly performed in a cloud environment.
- [WebJobs](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingWindowsAzureWebJobs.aspx)
- WorkerRole

**Background:** Assume there are many images that have to be resized. The list of images is defined in some table, all they are stored in azure blob. The list may change so I need to run tasks periodically, for example each hour.

I've read that WebJobs are more suited for such tasks especially if I already have some WebRole. And what about RunBooks? Are they worse? What I'm trying to figure out is any facts of their limitations for compute-intensive tasks (in terms of resources, cost and scalability). At the moment I can't find any information saying that Runbooks cannot scale, are slow and cost too much.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Automation's Runbooks is basically "Powershel-as-a-Service"...

so, do you want to resize your images via Powershell on a continous basis at a price of $87/mo on some non-scalabale, non-monitorable VM

OR.. would you rather use dynamically scalable, customizable and monitorable Cloud Services or Webjobs to do this?

IMHO, Automation Runbooks are best for administrative tasks that involve talking to Azure Powershell

Comment: Azure Automation is scalable, customizable, and monitorable. But I agree it is meant for administrative tasks (not just Azure PowerShell ones though), rather than for compute, storage, or memory intensive tasks. Automation's sandboxes are not meant for those tasks.

Comment: Correct, after some googling I've found only suggestions that they do well for administrative tasks. But what about other tasks? My goal is to find out if it is capable of processing X images per hour and how much it will cost (as a function of X). Then I can compare prices and decide between WebJobs and it. Any links are appreciated.